# How to change ?id=302 to /this-is-my-site.html after a GET POST form request?

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, get

OK, this is probably pretty easy, but I am just having a knuckle of a time trying to get it to work.

I have a small GET - form on a page with a text area (name=id).. when a person enters an ID number (which is just POST ID from a story) -- then I have it displayed in the URL like so:

```
http://mywebpage.com/page.php?id=582
```

So it just GETS the id from the URL and uses it in the query. I have a URL row in my table which is the title hypenated, like this: `this-is-my-site`, which just grabs the title of the story and runs it through a function really quick.

My question is, how would I keep the same format, but when the form gets submitted to look up the story by ID, then  how would I get the URL row in my title to replace my `?id=` variable??

So instead of

```
http://mywebpage.com/page.php?id=582
```

It would return

```
http://mywebpage.com/page.php/this-is-my-site.html
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mod_rewrite supports using an external lookup table file to translate urls, but it's just a simple static file and not suitable for highly dynamic sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
     $id=intval($_GET['id']); // sanitize it
     // get row by id
     //also we can redirect here to pretty url by 
     header('Location:'. $url)
}
else{
     //get by URI
}
```

PS: I don't know how to use database in rewrite(and .htaccess) but this solution need not it.
Use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: Then you would need some rewrite rule to capture the pretty url back in and do another db query.

Comment: @Shef we not really need rewrite here because of /index.php/ in URL $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']='/this-is-my-site.html' in this way. Yes we need 1 query more if we want to redirect.

Comment: @RiaD hmmm.. ?? still trying to piece this together... so I can use id to look up my url and then redirect them?

Answer (score 1):

Using htaccess is most definitely your best bet.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /page/(.*)$ /page/page.php?id=$1
```

That would rewrite your pages to

```
www.yoursite.com/page/3
```

This is pretty SEO friendly for your links.

Answer (score 1):

In `http://mywebpage.com/page.php?id=582`, you could check for the url-friendly name and use a `header('location: http://mywebpage.com/page.php/this-is-my-site.html');` to redirect to the url with the nice name.

After, you could check for the name (with .htaccess) and get the id from your database.